# php sort array by the average of numbers

Tags: php, average

I have an array (more than 4 keys) of integer values. I have to choose 4 different values, so that the average of these numbers will be equal to given one or false if it isnt possible.
What is the best way to do it? (algorithm)

Comment: @boomoto there's nothing wrong with asking for help for homework.

Comment: There are probably many ways to do it. Which ones have you tried, and which do you think is the best way, and why? Show your code and workings in the question...

Comment: sorry, it's not homework :D its for my job.. quite complex task

Comment: Quite complex? doesn't really sound that complex. Try something sir, we will be glad to help you with a foreach loop summing each element and diving it by the number of the elements of the array checking if its equal to the required average.. Ooooooooops, this is it.. Regardless the fact that it will be quite hard, as Mike said, that you can find a really precise average that will be exactly the same as the one of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I would accomplish it is find all of the possible subsets of the array of the given length and then loop through them and calculate their averages:

```
function get_subset_with_average($average, Array $data, $length) {
    // Make sure we can calculate the subsets
    if (count($data) < $length) {
        throw new Exception("The subset length is more than the size of the array");
    }
    $a = $b = 0;
    $subset = [];
    $subsets = [];

    // Loop through the data and get all subset combinations
    while ($a < count($data)) {
        $current = $data[$a++];
        $subset[] = $current;
        if (count($subset) == $length) {
            $subsets[] = $subset;
            array_pop($subset);
        }
        if ($a == count($data)) {
            $a = ++$b;
            $subset = [];
        }
    }

    // Loop through the subsets and check if the average equals the desired average
    foreach ($subsets as $set) {
        if (array_sum($set) / count($set) == $average) {
            return $set;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

var_dump(get_subset_with_average(2.5, $data, 4));
var_dump(get_subset_with_average(5.75, $data, 4));
var_dump(get_subset_with_average(9.3, $data, 4));
var_dump(get_subset_with_average(13, $data, 4));
```

This will output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
  [3]=>
  int(14)
}
bool(false)
bool(false)
```